# Can somebody identify this flowering bush?

Tags: identification

I think this is a bush, but I'm not sure. It has orange flowers that bloomed in July. Hummingbirds love it.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is Agastache rupestris, Threadleaf Giant Hyssop. [Threadleaf Giant Hyssop](https://www.google.com/search?q=lamiaceae&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=TRPsU5DOL4jxiwKW8YDwDA&ved=0CKcBEIke&biw=1333&bih=658#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=1X9W8PnWYwcYXM%253A%3BDbkGV6KmmTMxeM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.alamy.com%252Fthumbs%252F85d754b71cf44a74a298b43de5c7c548%252FThreadleaf-Giant-Hyssop-Agastache-rupestris-Lamiaceae-Aka-Licorice-D2GACH.jpg%253Fnoiptc%253Dtrue%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.alamy.com%252Fstock-photo-Threadleaf-Giant-Hyssop-Agastache-rupestris-Lamiaceae-Aka-Licorice-53219841.html%3B300%3B470)

Comment: Hey thanks! But this is considered a woody 'based' perennial. (never heard that term before)...

Comment: Ya, the reason I thought it was a bush is because it's woody.

Comment: @stormy That's because it doesn't die all the way back on it's own. I usually take them back farther than they naturally die.

Comment: They don't die back to the ground, they maintain a viable vascular system beneath woody cambium during a winter.  The best time to prune these guys is AFTER the winter and just before spring.  The old wood, dead branches/leaves actually help hold onto snow for insulation to ensure survival.  Wait 'till spring to cut back, yes? Grin...

Comment: So should I prune them all the way down to the ground?

Comment: @Ultravi01 hello! I think that you should create a new question to know more about prunning of _Agastache rupestris_ (Greene) Standl.

Comment: naw.. I'll take my chances.

Comment: @stormy I usually cut back these in spring also. It helps protect the plants during winter. I actually do most of my pruning in early spring.

Comment: We are all on the same page...thank you J.Musser!

Comment: When you prune in the spring, use shears and cut back to what looks healthy.  You should see tiny green buds developing and lots of dead tips.  Aim for a plant that is 2x as wide as it is high.  If the plant is 2' X 2', I'd cut the top flat at 1' and curve the sides down to a width of 1 1/2'.  Beautiful mixed with artichokes...